# Les « rallyes » non-dansant/sportif organisés par des groupuscules ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, anglicismes

Alors que l'ère de l'autorégulation de l'internet tire heureusement à sa fin, je lis avec plaisir qu'un groupuscule d'extrémistes qui avait organisé « plusieurs **rallyes** au Canada associés à l'extrême droite » a été [banni](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/techno/201904/08/01-5221347-canada-facebook-bannit-six-groupes-et-individus-dangereux.php) d'un réseau social populaire. Hormis les [sens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rallye) associés à des évènements sportifs et des soirées dansantes, ce qui n'était assurément pas le cas ici, je n'ai pas identifié cet emploi du mot rallye dans ce contexte-là.

S'agit-il d'un [anglicisme](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/rally), d'une extension d'une extension du sens du *rallye dansant* ou d'une cooccurrence sous-entendue particulière vu le contexte ? Est-ce ici un synonyme de [*rassemblement*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rassemblement) ou l'emploi du terme est-il tributaire d'une autre nuance ?

Answer (score 2):

En cherchant "Canadian Nationalist Front rally" sur Google, on voit que dans dans les résultats en anglais, cette organisation utilise toujours le terme "rally" pour désigner ses rassemblements. On peut donc imaginer que le journaliste n'a pas cherché plus loin et a simplement utilisé le même mot sous sa forme francisée (le pluriel anglais serait *rallies*).

Comment: Oui mais c'est qu'en anglais le terme peut vouloir dire rassemblement, en fait en prenant 10 secondes je ne peux même pas trouver d'autre terme en anglais pour le dire alors ce n'est pas que cette organisation-là en particulier emploie toujours le terme, le _political rally_ m'a l'air courant. Mais il est possible que le journaliste ait agi comme tu l'expliques parce que le terme existe en français, mais dans ce cas je serais porté à croire qu'il n'a pas compris le sens du terme en anglais. Mais ailleurs dans le texte de l'article on trouve le mot _rassemblement_. Je ne suis pas convaincu.